# Formulating a continuous NLP problem with a class variable

Tags: nonlinear-programming, constrained-optimization

In this minimization problem we have $N$ items, $j= 1, 2, \dots, N$ and a decision variable $x_j$ which are continuous values.
For every item, we have a nonlinear objective function $f$ in function of the decision variables $x_j$ that we want to minimize. We also have a variable $d_j$ that is different for every item and a variable $a_j$ that contains values from the set $\lbrace 0, 1, 2\rbrace$. Look at this $a$-variable as a classification that puts all items in one of three classes. I want to formulate the problem where we minimize $\sum_{j=1}^Nf(x_{j})$ but $x_j$ must be fixed for each class, so there are at most $3$ different values for $x_j$. Apart from that, we have the constraints $0.00 \le x_j < 1.00$ and $$\frac{\sum_{j=1}^N d_jx_{j}}{\sum_{j=1}^N d_j} = \beta,$$ where $0.00 \le \beta < 1.00$.

To make it a bit more clear, you can imagine the following table as an example of a valid (but not necessarily optimal) solution:

```
item    a    x     d     f(x)

1       0   0.98  198    212.5 
2       1   0.95  50     1245.2  
3       0   0.98  110    100.2     
4       2   0.92  20     120.8
5       1   0.95  80     521.2
6       1   0.95  36     8232.1
7       0   0.98  109    3245.7
8       2   0.92  15     58.2
9       0   0.98  140    5123.2
10      2   0.92  10     4128
```

In this valid solution, $\beta = 0.97$ and the result of the objective function is $22987.1$.

**How can I formulate this NLP problem by enforcing the constraints mentioned?**

Comment: As written, your ratio constraint forces all $x_i$ to be equal to $\beta$.  Are you maybe missing a $\sum_i$ somewhere?

Comment: The constraint containing $\beta$ has a subscript $i$ that is neither summed over nor qualified. Should we assume that the constraint is enforced for each $i?$

Comment: @RobPratt does it make sense to index my x variable on i and j ? Or do I just need to index on j and constraint it to be the same for the same values of a ?

Comment: Still trying to understand.  What is the explicit formula for $f$?

Comment: @RobPratt the column $a$ is the result of a classification that is done for each item. $x_j$ can be a number between 0.00 and 1 but it must be a fixed number for each classification, so you can't have two different values for $x_j$ when the number in column $a$ is the same. At the end, the ratio of the sum $x_jd_j$ and the sum of $d_j$ must be equal to a fixed ratio $\beta$. $f$ is an ugly polynomial with non-integer coefficients (don't know if it would help to have it explicitly out there). I edited the question make it a bit more clear (I hope at least).

Comment: You call $x_j$ a decision variable but $a_j$ and $d_j$ variables. Do you mean that $a_j$ and $d_j$ are fixed as part of the input and the problem is to find optimal values for $x_j$?  Also, is $\beta$ a fixed constant input or a decision variable that are we free to choose?

Comment: @RobPratt $a_j$ and $d_j$ are known upfront and we can't adjust these in finding a solution. We only can decide on the values of $x_j$ indeed. Also, $\beta$ is a fixed constant that is chosen upfront and not something we can adjust (that would lead to $x_j = 0$ for all $j$ I guess).

Comment: Gurobi (and most other solvers) provide some tutorial examples where they index decision variable over some other set of variables like x over days, machines, categories etc. https://www.gurobi.com/jupyter_models/

Comment: In constraint programming, an [ELEMENT constraint](https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_035/casmopt/casmopt_clpsolver_syntax08.htm) can model such relationships where a decision variable's index can itself be a decision variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given, $a_j\in\{0,1,2\}$, $d_j$, and $\beta$, your problem is to find $x_0,x_1,x_2\in [0,1]$ to minimize $\sum_{j=1}^N f(x_{a_j})$ subject to
$$\frac{\sum_{j=1}^N d_j x_{a_j}}{\sum_{j=1}^N d_j} = \beta.$$

---

For example, here's what it would look like in SAS, where I have used $f(x)=(x-1/2)^4$:

```
data indata;
   input item a d;
   datalines;
 1 0 198
 2 1  50
 3 0 110
 4 2  20
 5 1  80
 6 1  36
 7 0 109
 8 2  15
 9 0 140
10 2  10
;

proc optmodel;
   set ITEMS;
   num a {ITEMS};
   num d {ITEMS};
   num beta = 0.97;
   set LABELS = setof {j in ITEMS} a[j];

   read data indata into ITEMS=[item] a d;

   var X {LABELS} >= 0 <= 1;
   min Z = sum {j in ITEMS} (X[a[j]] - 1/2)^4;
   con Ratio:
      (sum {j in ITEMS} d[j] * X[a[j]]) / (sum {j in ITEMS} d[j]) = beta;

   solve;
   print a d {j in ITEMS} X[a[j]];
quit;
```

Comment: thanks for the additional explanation on the implementation. Managed to get it working in Pyomo as well. Thanks again!! Accepted and upvoted.